# Programmatically rename functions

Tags: javascript, compiler-optimization

I am currently writing an ECMAScipt5 compiler that performs various given optimizations/transformations on a parse tree and compiles back to ECMAScipt5.

One functionality is to rename a *Binding* in an *EnvironmentRecord*.

This transformation may either be performed automatically e.g. as part of an optimization that aims to reduce code size, where each variable (not in the global scope) will be given the next shortest available name, or manually by an annotation after a statement that introduces a new scope.

However, I have to restrict the (automatic) process to variable declarations only.

Consider those two examples. The first, compiled, specifying `[Minify]` as transformations, the second one using `[Directives, PrettyPrint]`

*Syntax: `Compiler.fromSource (src).compile ([/*Array of transformations*/]);`*

```
var bar,foo;
(function exampleMin () {
    var bar="foo",
        foo="bar";
    
    function fooBar () {
        return foo + bar;
    }
})
```

compiles to

`var bar,foo;function exampleMin(){var A="foo",B="bar";function fooBar(){return B+A}}`

And

```
var bar,foo;
(function exampleMin () {
    @Rename bar:A
    @Rename foo:B
    @Rename fooBar:C
    var bar="foo",
        foo="bar";
    
    function fooBar () {
        return foo + bar;
    }
})
```

compiles to

```
var bar,foo;
function exampleMin(){
     var A="foo",B="bar";
     function C(){
          return B+A;
     }
};
```

Which leads to the problematic part, functions... consider the following

```
if (fooBar.name === 'fooBar') {
 //...
}
```

Now, if this statement would be contained in `exampleMin`. The user defined rename would have transformed the code into a semantically different code. Which must not ever happen by an automatic performed transformation.

While I blindly assume that user defined renaming of functions doesn't change the semantics somehow, I would like to produce a warning if that may be the case. But I don't know **how to determine whether it's safe to rename a function programmatically** or not.

This brings me down to the questions:

1. What, besides accessing a functions name has to be considered when renaming a function?
2. What analysis has to be performed to mark a function as either safely optimizable or not. Is it possible at all.
3. Would I rather exclude functions from being renamed or would I try to change the other side of e.g. a comparison against a functions name too. (If it can be proved to have no side effects either)
4. Would a change in the semantics be tolerable in such a specific case *([GCC](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com) seems to think so)*, if I, in exchange, offer a `@do-not-optimize` annotation?

---

Update 1.

I have come to the conclusion that this analysis might be not possible solely through static analysis

Consider the following code.

```
function foo () {}
function bar () {}
var fns = [bar,foo];

if (fns [0].name === 'bar') fns [0] ();

fns.unshift (foo);

if (fns [1].name === 'bar') fns [1] ();
```

I can't imagine how to track the references back to it's origin once a function has been added to an array,  without executing the code. Maybe i would need some form of Abstract Interpretation<sup>[1](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com)</sup>?

---

Update2

In the mean-time and after reading @Genes answer, I realized there are other few things that may not hurt to be added. First, some side notes:

- Apparently I am not writing a compiler, but rather a *preprocessor* since it outputs sourcecode and not machine code.
- Given that there would only be static accesses of bound Identifiers, I have a good idea on how to approach the problem.
- Each *Binding* in every *environment record* currently holds a list to all its static references *(I obviously couldn't add dynamic ones*)

I am currently working on the SSA<sup>[2]</sup> conversion. So I haven't yet implemented any DataFlow analysis yet. But that's on the plan.

So for the sake of simplicity, let's just assume the following prerequisites would be met.

- AST and CFG are in Static Single Assignment form.
- GEN and KILL sets have been computed for each node in the CFG<sup>[4](http://ssabook.gforge.inria.fr/latest/book.pdf)</sup>
- Reaching Definitions<sup>[4](http://ssabook.gforge.inria.fr/latest/book.pdf)</sup> / IN and OUT sets have been computed.
- DEF / USE pairs have been computed
- *flow dependence edges* have been added to the CFG

  So the Control Flow Graph(s) for the first example could look something like this.

[image]

- The black, non-dotted lines represent control flow edges.
- The black dotted connections represent dataflow dependencies
- The blue double arrow lines represent call sites.
- The blue dotted lines represent interprocedural dependencies. *I'm however not sure if i should make a direct connection between the corresponding nodes of each precedures CFG*

Given this, I could know simply perform the following.

For each function that is about to be renamed:

- Visit its declarations CFG node
- For each *flow dependency* edge visit the target node
- If that node is a conditional goto statement and the functions reference is the LHS of a *property accessor* with the RHS being "name".

  - Mark the function as tainted

The only problem is **I can't see how to compute (even approximate) that information for non-static references of a function**.

Soo, if that analysis doesn't help finding **ALL** references to a function, i could as well use the beforementioned list of references, that each *Binding* in an *environment record* holds.
Since a function has a *declarative environment record* **as well as** an *object environment record*. I could simply take a look at the count of references of its *object environments* "name" *Binding*.

As a reference, here is the actual code that currently performs the renaming

```
var boundIdentifiers = this.environment.record.bindings, //`this` refers to an AST node representing a FunctionDeclaration or a FunctionExpression
    nextName, 
    identifier, 
    binding;

for (identifier in boundIdentifiers) {
    binding = boundIdentifiers [identifier];
    if (binding.uses < 2 && !binding.FunctionExpression) {
        compiler.pushWarning (binding.references [0].line, binding.references [0].column,'Declared function ' + identifier + ' is never called.') //False positive if the functions reference is obtained dynamically
    }

    if (boundIdentifiers [identifier].FunctionDeclaration || boundIdentifiers [identifier].FunctionExpression) {
        continue; //Skip function declarations and expressions, since their name property could be accessed
    }

    do {
        nextName = nextVar (); 
    } while (
        Object.hasOwnProperty.call (boundIdentifiers,nextVar) //There could exist a `hasOwnProperty` binding.
    ); //ther could a with the name that already exists in the scope. So make sure we have assign a free name.

    this.environment.record.setBindingName (identifier, nextName);
}
```

**So the overall problem boils down to catching non-static references**

What analysis techniques and prior optimizations would need to be involved to catch at least some (since its not possible to *catch em all*), non-static references.

---

<sub>*I modified the questions to fit the update. So, the above questions still apply*</sub>

[1][A Survey of Static Program Analysis Techniques](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Elopes/teaching/inf212W12/readings/Woegerer-progr-analysis.pdf) *(CH: 2)*
[2][Static Single Assignment Book](http://ssabook.gforge.inria.fr/latest/book.pdf)
[4][Representation and Analysis of Software](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Elopes/teaching/inf212W12/readings/rep-analysis-soft.pdf)

---

As *@didierc* mentioned in the comments, the same problem arises for property accesses using the bracket notation. So *Bindings* of an *object environment record* can be renamed manually only.

Comment: I doubt its possible to be sure through static analysis. If you really need to not break code, you could not rename functions at all.

Comment: @soktinpk Google Closure Compiler does rename functions, so it has to be possible, i wouldn't mind more complex analysis. Excluding them from renaming is what i do currently in the minification task, but it could save a whole lot of characters. If accessing the name property is all i have to worry, i thought about something like this: If I compute the aliases before I define the *Binding* s of *ObjectEnvironmentRecord* s,I could probably check if there is more than one reference to the functions *ObjectEnvironmentRecord* s "name" *Binding*. If so, mark the function as unsafe for renaming.

Comment: The solution to this problem is not to use the non-standard [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) at all - you say your code is ES5. It wouldn't work in some browsers anyway.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Google Closure Compiler does rename functions, but it does so unsafely. For example try minifying: `(function() {
function hello(name) {
  alert('Hello, ' + name);
}

if (hello.name === "hello") hello(hello.name);
})();`. The output doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi So that would mean if i choose to unsafely rename functions, only the use of the name property could lead to semantically different generated code? Which is toleratable, since it's non-standard? (Like GCC does). -  Yes the compiler won't work in all browsers since it's ES5, but where does that relate to, the code the compiler produces, being semantically different from the previous? If the Input is valid ES3, the compiler generates valid ES3 which runs on every browser.

Comment: @soktinpk Oh thanks for that, well, that renders my first argument invalid. I wonder what's preventing this analysis. If it's simple due to `name` being a non-standard property and not worthy of being accounted for or if the computational complexity doesn't outweight the benefits of the transformation being safe

Comment: Well, I'm sure some other things may break (like Function's `toString` - used in some DI frameworks for getting parameter names), but yes - I think breaking non-standard stuff is tolerable. By mentioning ES5 I meant that the feature is nonstandard in ES<=5 (it may become a standard with ES6).

Comment: How do you handle things like `foo['bar']();`?

Comment: @didierc Since the bracket could contain any valid expression,  not only constants.  I can't perform an automatic optimization.  So an annotation has to be used, since the process could change the semantics.  I'll probably emit a warning If I there is any property access of an object, where a rename will be performed,  containing an  expression, that the transformation is unsafe.  So the user has to take care that it doesn't break anything. (that was a pain to type on mobile)

Comment: Then, it's basically the same problem as checking a function name, but within the strict language scope of ecmascript 5? I was trying to find a situation which would render an automatic renaming invalid. I don't think that language like CoffeeScript (which are targetting js) authorize that construct in their own language, so they may safely apply renamings as they see fit, but if your language accepts it, then you have to take it in account.

Comment: (Oh, and imagine if you had only a keypad on your phone...)

Comment: @didierc Exactly! :) A simple *(ES6 for shortness)* example would be `var a=['foo','bar'],b={foo:()=>0,bar:()=>0}; for(i=2;i--;) b[a[i]]()`. Renaming `b.foo -> b.a` and `b.bar -> b.b` would break the code. I can't think of any way to solve this, but i would love to hear a possible way, regardless if there is only an approximating way. *(Also I din't knew CoffeeScript had no bracket notation, yes that makes this problem easier)*

Comment: (IIRC I could type pretty fast on keypad only phones, better than on virtual keyboards, there should simply be a morse button with haptic feedback to allow for blind texting)

Comment: My bad: for some reason I thought of CoffeeScript, but it's not one of these languages that I meant, although now I wonder which language I really meant: perhaps something like elm, where static typing cannot accomodate dynamic slot invocation? Anyway, my point was that as soon as you may form symbol names dynamically (using the bracket notation, `eval`, or some other facility), it's impossible to garantee that a source transformation will not invalidate its semantics.

Comment: (Actually, with predictive technology, keypads are quite usable - otoh, automatic correction can be annoying).

Comment: @didierc :). Yes, that's what I figured. So the question is, how to handle that. Trigger deopts  for objects that either get accessesd dynamically or have been assigned to an array or object that get's accessed dynamically? Or tolerate broken code when reflection is used. I btw like Phil H.'s answer, but I don't get how to achieve that.

Comment: I try to clean that answer a bit up, now that it has an nice answer

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4  This article http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/115734/aitypes.pdf shows how abstract interpretation can be used for type inference in Javascript JIT.  It might help you see possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't "break" the interpreter as @Phil H says, which is a valid solution if possible...

The normal way that compilers handle cases like this is called dataflow analysis.  This amounts to a code walk computing values that describe the program structure in some ways.  In all interesting cases, the values are converative estimates.

The most prevalent conservative assumptions are that nothing is known about which `if` branch will execute, that the number of times a loop will iterate is also unknown, and that nothing is known about what a function call might do in terms of side effects.  Sophisticated kinds of *interprocedural dataflow analysis* allow dropping the last one.  E.g. LLVM is capable of this, but many other compilation systems are not.

The special conservative assumption for this problem is that if `.name` or similar introspection is used on a value, then it's "tainted."  It can't be renamed.  Dataflow analysis will let you find a conservative list of tainted namees.

For this problem, the dataflow analysis that probably applies best is def-use analysis to construct "use chains" attached to each "definition". In javascript, definition is equivalent to assingment and function naming.  If your analysis is sophisticated enough to look inside hashes, then adding a key-value pair is a def.

The analysis result will be a list attached to each definition of each "use" of the value established during that definition.  The conservative assumptions mean that the list may include uses that never actually occur.

There is a huge literature on dataflow analysis.  But an excellent way to start learning about it is the old standard "dragon book", Aho Sethi and Ullman, *Compiler Design*.

**Addition**

The problem with very dynamic languages is that accurate dataflow analysis is hard.  The example in comments:

```
var n='name';
function foo () {}; 
if (foo[n] === 'foo') doSth ()
```

is typical.  The dumb conservative assumption is that in any indexing operation `a[s]`, the `s` might be `'name'`.  So `a` can't be renamed.  You must overcome the limits of dumb assumptions by making the dataflow analysis more detailed - less of an estimate.

A framework for this is [*abstract interpretation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation): actually running the program with an abstract value domain replacing real data, again making conservative assumptions about `if`s and loops.  If the abstract domain has certain properties, a finite length execution is guarenteed to compute final values for each variable.  Constant folding is a simple form of abstract interpretation.

In your example, the abstract value domain would have to include at least something like

```
{ unassigned, constant string, unknown }
```

In practice you'll also want `null`, constant numbers, functions, and other values. The abstract interpretation lingo would say "bottom" instead of "unassigned" and "top" instead of "unknown."

All this is old stuff. Therefore there is an enormous formal literature on it starting in the 60's, when people were very interested in optimizing lisp compilers. If you can get access, search the ACM archives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)  I already read a lot of awesome literature on dataflow analysis. And if all `.name` references would be static, i guess that could be done even without dataflow analysis. So the question I'm asking  could be formulated as: What prior analysis is needed to build DEF/USE pairs for **dynamic** definitions and uses like. `var n='name';function foo () {}; if (foo[n] === 'foo') doSth ()`. When building def use chains, I would totally miss the use of `foo`s name property without prior constant propagation. Sorry If I didn't made that clear in the question. I updated it now

Comment: I like your answer anyway since it partially answers the question nicely and gives a good overview for future visitors :)

Comment: I also should probably read my comments a second time before I submit them. I hope the first one is not too confusingly worded.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 I made an addition. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: btw, the site you're linking to in your profile says its url has been replaced by http://bridgecontest.org/

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Thanks.  The piece of Abs Interp you need is just the idea that the domain must be a finite lattice and operators must be monotonic (results are upper bounds of arguments in the domain lattice). Say instead of computing over all integers you compute over { undefined, negative, zero, positive, unknown }. Now redefine math and comparison ops over this domain: `positive + positive` is positive, but `positive + negative` is unkown, etc.  Then run the program with these new rules. Things do get more complicated if you try to interpret application of function values.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to break the `.name` property to return the original name instead of the new name. Nothing else will work.

Consider replacing all .name with ._name(), and constructing a lookup table of ref->name.

Comment: How would i handle non static references of the name property like `foo['name']`. Even worse, `a=[foo],p=name;a[0][p]==='foo'&&a[0]()`. The problem lies somehow in tracking all references to the original function, since at any point, a function is being referenced, following a dynamic property access. It could be the "name" property. While some of those accesses could probably turned into static ones, by applying e.g. Sparse Conditional Constant Propagation, there surely will be those who won't. If i don't find all references, I can't replace them. *(or am i missing something crucial here?)*

Comment: Or do you mean to actually redefine a functions name property? :)  If so, do you know a possible way? I'm not a 100 sure but afaik you can't redefine a functions name in ECMAScript5

Comment: By 'break', I mean by modifying the interpreter. I don't think you'll be able to do any replacements like this for the reasons you are describing; all reflections will fail unless you can still use the original property names in an identical way to that without renaming.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 I created a simple code example that, I think, represents Phils idea: http://jsfiddle.net/CCN5R/1/ Just imaging the code your looking at is already minified code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that renaming a function is unsafe, the problem is that code which depends on "name" property of a function is unsafe, regardless of the renaming you are considering.

Consider that a function object's 'name' property isn't defined in the ecma standard, and that some browsers therefor don't implement it.   In JavaScript functions can be nameless, or may have several names, so taking a dependency on a browser-specific name property in code is the problem, not the concept of renaming functions.

Comment: Thanks for that Answer, that's one thing I wanted to hear. I like the formulation that code depending on non-standard properties,  per se, is unsafe. So the renaming is justified.  One thing that puzzles me a bit though, is, how can  a function have multiple names?